C# MVC Syncfusion script как сделать "полосатый грид"?
доброе время суток, коллеги!
в MVC5 через библиотеки Syncfusion выводятся данные в виде таблицы
                    <div class="panel-body">
                @(Html.EJ().Button("refreshLine1").Text("обновить").ClientSideEvents(d => d.Click("UpdateLineEvents")))
                @{
                    @(Html.EJ().Grid<object>("FlatGrid1")
                                      .AllowPaging()
                                      .AllowSorting()
                                      .AllowFiltering()
                                      .ShowColumnChooser()
                                      .AllowResizeToFit()
                                
                                      .Locale("ru-RU")
                                  
                                      .ClientSideEvents(c =>
                                      {
                                          c.ActionComplete("completeAction");
                                          c.RowSelected("rowSelected");
                                      })
                                      .FilterSettings(filter => { filter.FilterType(FilterType.Excel); })
                                    .Datasource(ds => ds.Json( ViewData["LineEvents"])).Columns(col =>                                      
                                    {
                                        col.Field("Id").HeaderText("Id").IsPrimaryKey(true).Width(40).Add();
                                        col.Field("Job").HeaderText("План").Width(80).Add();
                                        col.Field("StartDate").HeaderText("Начало").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy H:mm}").Width(80).Add();
                                        col.Field("EndDate").HeaderText("Окончание").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy H:mm}").Width(80).Add();
                                        col.Field("Duration").HeaderText("Длительность").Width(80).Add();
                                        col.Field("Status").HeaderText("Статус").Width(30).TextAlign(TextAlign.Center).Add();
                                        col.Field("EventName").HeaderText("Событие").Width(80).Add();
                                        col.Field("LineName").HeaderText("Линия").Width(75).Add();
                                        col.Field("Area").HeaderText("Участок").Width(75).Add();
                                        col.Field("Shift").HeaderText("Смена").Visible(false).Width(75).Add();
                                        col.Field("PersonStart").HeaderText("Запустил").Visible(false).Width(75).Add();
                                        col.Field("PersonEnd").HeaderText("Остановил").Visible(false).Width(75).Add();
                                   
                                    }
                                )
                                .ClientSideEvents(eve => eve.QueryCellInfo("querycellinfo"))
                    )
                }
            </div>

функция querycellinfo - скрипт

<script>
   function querycellinfo(args) {
    if (args.column.field == "Id") { 
       if (args.data.Id % 2 == 0) { 
           $($(args.cell).parent()).css("backgroundColor", "#DCDCDC"); 
        } 
     } 
   } 
</script>

все работает отлично, пока не используется сортировка/фильтр.
вопрос: как мне скриптом покрасить только четные строки в таблице?
заранее спасибо

Поправки вносите в сам вопрос, его можно редактировать, а комментарий удалить.

Это называется alternate rows. По этому термину легко ищется документация: Style and Appearance - задайте e-altrow.

Александр, большое спасибо!

итак, смотрим в направлении css
минимальный набор стилей
    <style> 
        .e-grid .e-row {
    background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
     }
    </style>

